# DataTables warning: invalid JSON response when there are no records in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter with the bootstrap datatable to display the records from the database.

I am getting the error when there are no records are available in the table.

> DataTables warning: table id=employee-List - Invalid JSON response.
>   For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/1

Records are displaying when available in the table.

I tried to find out the solution on SO but none of the solutions is working for me. Can aneone assist me what's the issue with my code?

I tried @BlueWater86 answer, the error goes off but my records are not displaying.

Would you help me out with this issue?

[image]

My code is,

**Script**

```
$('#employee-List').DataTable({
  language: {
    sLengthMenu: "Show _MENU_", // remove entries text
    searchPlaceholder: "Search",
    emptyTable: "No record found",
    search: ""
  },
  "ordering": false, // remove sorting effect from header 
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "scrollX": true,
  "bInfo": false,
  "pageLength": 10,
  "ajax": {
    "url": baseUrl + "/Employee_control/fetch_employeeList",
    "type": "POST",
    "dataSrc": ""
  },
  "columns": [{
      "data": "id",
      "className": "reg_bg"
    },
    {
      "data": "name"
    },
    {
      "data": "email"
    },
    {
      "data": "mobileno"
    },
    {
      "data": "emp_id"
    },
    {
      "data": "address"
    },
    {
      "data": "action"
    }
  ]

});
```

**Controller**

```
public function fetch_employeeList(){
  $order_list=$this->Employee_model->fetch_employeeList();

// Datatables Variables
$draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
$start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
$length = intval($this->input->get("length"));

$data['draw'] = 1;
$data['recordsTotal'] = count($order_list);
$data['recordsFiltered'] = count($order_list);
foreach ($order_list as $key => $row) 
{
$action='<a href="" class="action-btn action-btn-border">View</a><a href="" class="action-btn action-btn-red-bg">Archive</a>';
$arr_result = array(
            "id" =>$row->id,
            "name" => $row->firstname." ".$row->middlename." ".$row->lastname,
            "email" => $row->email_id,
            "mobileno" => $row->mobileno,
            "emp_id" => $row->employee_id,
            "address" => $row->address,
            "action" => $action
);

$data['data'][] = $arr_result;

}
//print_r($arr_result);
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
}
```

**Model**

```
public function fetch_employeeList(){
        $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('tbl_employee');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        if($result)
      {
          return $result;
      }
      else{
          return 0;
      }
    }
```

Comment: why did you comment the `serverSide:true` parameter if you are getting your data in your controller?

Comment: Actually, I was trying to find the solution for this issue.  I enable it.

Comment: Have you inspected the data comping back from the ajax call to `/Employee_control/fetch_employeeList`? You have introduced this bug by returning two different types from the `fetch_employeeList` function (object if there are employees; integer if there aren't employees).

Comment: @BlueWater86, In the network tab response I am getting the error Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable                   because of no records in table

Comment: So does `fetch_employeeList` always return an object that implements Countable?

Comment: @BlueWater86, Yes, It always returns the object. It will count the records.

Comment: I apologise for sounding cryptic, I will just post an answer instead.

Comment: try to check order_list variable if empty or not then if not perform count() `if (empty($order_list)){
        //assign static value here
        }else{
        $data['recordsTotal'] = count($order_list);
        $data['recordsFiltered'] = count($order_list);
        }`

Answer (score 1):

In a statically typed language this sort of issue would not be encountered. If you consider the interface of the `fetch_employeeList()` function, it returns a dynamic; sometimes an array of objects and sometimes the number 0.

You should return an empty array instead of the number 0 in the case that there are no employee query results.

```
public function fetch_employeeList(){
        $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('tbl_employee');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        if($result)
      {
          return $result;
      }
      else{
          return [];
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, Error goes off and I am getting "No record found" Now I added one records but I am not getting that... checking again from my side.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I got one more issue in this. The issue is, I have records in the table but that records are not displaying because I added ""dataSrc": "" " in the ajax call. If I comment dataSrc then displaying the records.

Comment: Your comments are now getting very hard to follow. It sounds like you are now asking for a tutorial rather than the solution of an individual problem. Your initial problem is resolved.

Comment: Yes, My initial issue is resolved. I shared my second issue because I thought you know the solution...No problem, I'll try from my side. Thanks for help and support.

Comment: If I understood your comment with a code example I would have given assistance.